# How to configure gwt remote logging in multi module project?

Tags: gwt, exception

I want to configure gwt remote logging in a multi-module project. Every module is having its own entry point. So do I need to add GWT.setUncaughtexceptionHandler{...} logic in every modules entry point method or only in the module which is loaded first. Which one is the best approach? If I should add the exception handling only in the module which is loaded first then how will the exceptions from other modules get handled when they are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UncaughtexceptionHandler will allow to catch just Exception for the current module.
Each module will have is own iframe who execute the gwt javascript code.

GWT Logging allready have a remote logging :
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Remote_Logging

Just add a property in all modules.xml and you will have the remote logging.